# Import image from Enterprise Architect to ms Word

Tags: c#, .net, import, enterprise-architect

Working on an Enterprise Architect add-in I want to import an image from Enterprise Architect to ms Word using c#. For now I have solved this by saving the diagram/image as a .pdf file and then reading it again using the iTextSharp.
It seems to me that this is the hard way around the problem and therefore I think there must be a more simple way to get the image from Enterprise Architect to ms Word using c#.

Comment: So, have you tried anything?

Comment: I tried looking at the interface EA.diagram to see if there was anything in there I could use. The only thing I found there was the "SaveAsPDF" command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you insert the image straight into the document?

```
//create a document generator
EA.DocumentGenerator generator;  


//initialize the document generator to create empty document (with no EA template)
generator = Repository.CreateDocumentGenerator();
generator.NewDocument("");

//insert image to the document
generator.DocumentDiagram(diagram.DiagramID, 0, "Diagram Image Template");  

//save the documrnt
generator.SaveDocument(@"path/of/word/document/with/extension", 0);
```

The `"Diagram Image Template"` is a template you have to define yourself in EA by following these easy steps:
    1. Click F8
2.Go to the Templates tab
3.Click on the `new` button on he bottom
4.Give the new template the name `"Diagram Image Template"`, and click OK. A document of new template will be opened.
5.On the left panel of the document, select the `Diagram` checkbox. Some text will be added to the document on the right.
6.In the template document, right click where you see the text `[right-click-to-insert-Diagram-field(s)]` -> Insert Field -> Diagram Image.
7.Save the template.

Comment: That's an easier approach of the problem. But know I'm having a problem with the registration:
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {ED685310-1B2F-486F-8BD0-8A753DD6054D} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
I tried converting the platform target from "Any CPU" to "x86" and "x64" but none of that did help me.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Did you try the way I suggested?

Comment: Yes I tried what you suggested but I had to assign the variable, so I did like this:
EA.DocumentGenerator generator = new EA.DocumentGenerator();
And then I get the error as I posted before.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to post how to initialize the generator. See the edited code!

Comment: Almost there now!
The code is running without making any errors, but the image is no where to see in the generated document. Could this be because of a bad image format or or a wrong imageID?

Comment: Never mind. Found out that the filename I wrote had .docx in the end which were causing the error. Working fine now and thanks for your help! Very useful!

Comment: You welcome. Of course you can add to the generator either text by the InsertText method, and other goodies...

Comment: What if I want to add the image to a word document that is already open and I want to continue working on it?

Comment: What do you mean in 'already opened'? Why don't you try to use the generator to insert more things to the document, after the image, and then save it? Did you try to add the image to an existing opened document?

Comment: I found the solution I was looking for and posted it as an answer in this question. Never mind the question I asked before. I got everything I need :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the clipboard function. This particular code opens a new word document, copies the image from a diagram in EA and paste it into a paragraph.

```
public void getPicture(Repository repository)
    {
        Object item;
        ObjectType ot = repository.GetTreeSelectedItem(out item);

        Word.Application wapp = GetWordApp();
        var document = wapp.Documents.Add();
        var paragraph = document.Paragraphs.Add();

        Project project = repository.GetProjectInterface();

        if (ot == ObjectType.otDiagram)
        {
            Diagram d = (Diagram)item;
            project.PutDiagramImageOnClipboard(d.DiagramGUID, 0);
            paragraph.Range.Paste();
        }
    }

        private Word.Application GetWordApp()
    {
        Word.Application wapp = new Word.Application();
        wapp.Visible = true;
        return wapp;
    }
```

Comment: By further investigation it seems like a bad practice to have your code "steal" the clipboard, cause the clipboard should only be used in "user-land". Anyway it seems like the best workarounds is to write the picture into a temporary file where you can read it from.